# How can I make Highcharts label a datetime X-axis with relative dates?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following chart that displays multiple curves. These curves all occurred at different times, but I'm aligning them so that they can be viewed as if they occurred at the same time. You can view the *actual* date for each point by hovering over the point.

```js
//set global chart options
$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
    },

    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'FIXME',
        style: {
          color: '#4bb2c5',
        },
      },
      min: 0,
      maxPadding: 0,
    }, ],

    legend: {
      labelFormat: '<span style="font-size: xx-small;">{name}</span>',
    },

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.point.name) + "<br>Cases: " + this.point.y;
      }
    },
  });

  drawGraphMultipleCurves();
});

var plotMultipleCurves = null;

function drawGraphMultipleCurves() {
  //no need to redraw if we've already drawn the graph
  if (plotMultipleCurves != null)
    return;

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves549 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 9, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 8, 0),
      y: 2,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 15, 0),
      y: 7,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 22, 0),
      y: 14,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 17, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 29, 0),
      y: 33,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 24, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 6, 0),
      y: 50,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 13, 0),
      y: 65,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 20, 0),
      y: 97,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 15, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 27, 0),
      y: 128,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 22, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 3, 0),
      y: 192,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 10, 0),
      y: 239,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 17, 0),
      y: 298,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 12, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 24, 0),
      y: 366,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 19, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
      y: 439,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 8, 0),
      y: 543,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 15, 0),
      y: 623,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 22, 0),
      y: 692,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 29, 0),
      y: 738,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 5, 0),
      y: 783,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 12, 0),
      y: 819,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 19, 0),
      y: 836,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 26, 0),
      y: 850,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 2, 0),
      y: 864,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 9, 0),
      y: 875,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 16, 0),
      y: 881,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 13, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 23, 0),
      y: 884,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 20, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 2, 0),
      y: 885,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 9, 0),
      y: 888,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 16, 0),
      y: 890,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 11, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 23, 0),
      y: 892,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 18, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves805 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 2,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 2, 0),
      y: 4,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 3, 0),
      y: 5,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 28, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 4, 0),
      y: 7,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 5, 0),
      y: 9,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 6, 0),
      y: 19,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 7, 0),
      y: 34,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 8, 0),
      y: 53,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 9, 0),
      y: 88,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 10, 0),
      y: 114,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 11, 0),
      y: 129,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 12, 0),
      y: 154,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 7, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 13, 0),
      y: 186,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 14, 0),
      y: 212,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 15, 0),
      y: 231,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 16, 0),
      y: 269,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 11, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 17, 0),
      y: 300,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 12, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 18, 0),
      y: 317,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 13, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 19, 0),
      y: 327,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 14, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 20, 0),
      y: 352,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 15, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 21, 0),
      y: 381,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 22, 0),
      y: 412,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 17, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 23, 0),
      y: 441,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 18, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 24, 0),
      y: 489,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 19, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 25, 0),
      y: 507,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 20, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 26, 0),
      y: 546,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 21, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 27, 0),
      y: 605,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 22, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 28, 0),
      y: 656,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 29, 0),
      y: 701,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 24, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 30, 0),
      y: 762,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 25, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
      y: 832,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 894,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 3, 0),
      y: 941,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 28, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 4, 0),
      y: 959,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 5, 0),
      y: 980,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 6, 0),
      y: 1005,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 31, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 7, 0),
      y: 1036,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 8, 0),
      y: 1062,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 9, 0),
      y: 1074,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 10, 0),
      y: 1105,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 11, 0),
      y: 1154,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 12, 0),
      y: 1192,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 13, 0),
      y: 1218,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 7, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 14, 0),
      y: 1268,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 15, 0),
      y: 1302,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 16, 0),
      y: 1332,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 17, 0),
      y: 1357,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 11, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves534 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 0,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 30, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 30, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 30, 0),
      y: 5,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 30, 0),
      y: 9,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
      y: 21,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 301,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 2, 0),
      y: 735,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
      y: 964,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 2, 0),
      y: 1041,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
      y: 1044,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 1044,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves550 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 222,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
      y: 546,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 1, 0),
      y: 920,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
      y: 2247,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 1, 0),
      y: 70613,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 1, 0),
      y: 108834,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
      y: 161916,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 168862,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 1, 0),
      y: 170018,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
      y: 170170,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 1, 0),
      y: 170252,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
      y: 170324,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 170379,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves537 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 202,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 453,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 2, 0),
      y: 640,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 30, 0),
      y: 931,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 31, 0),
      y: 1387,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 30, 0),
      y: 2256,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 2, 0),
      y: 3701,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 5302,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 2, 0),
      y: 6353,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 2, 0),
      y: 7156,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 2, 0),
      y: 7804,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 2, 0),
      y: 8351,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 8839,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 11, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //plot the graph
  plotMultipleCurves = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'multipleCurves',
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Outbreak comparison',
    },

    series: [

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves549,
        name: '64% | Australia (2008)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 5,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#800026',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves805,
        name: '52% | Portugal (2012)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 4,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#fd9841',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves534,
        name: '46% | China (2006)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 3,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#fee288',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves550,
        name: '46% | Brazil (2001)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#ffe691',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves537,
        name: '45% | Singapore (2006)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#ffeda0',
      },
    ],

    xAxis: [{
      labels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      tickLength: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Time',
      },
    }],

    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Cumulative cases',
      },
      min: 0,
      maxPadding: 0,
    }],

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="multipleCurves"></div>
```

The problem right now is that the X-axis ticks/labels are blank. It clearly doesn't make sense to allow Highcharts to place dates for the X-axis labels. Instead of placing *absolute* dates, I want to place *relative* dates. Basically, I want a way to determine how long the longest time series is and scale the relative labels appropriately. Here are some examples:

- In the graph I show above, it makes sense to have labels such as "Month 1", "Month 2", "Month 3", etc. And, if there are too many labels/ticks, then it would skip the appropriate amount (e.g., "Month 1", "Month 4", "Month 7")
- If the longest time series were a lot shorter (say, 30 days), then the labels would be "Day 1", "Day 2", etc. Similarly, it would skip labels/ticks when appropriate (e.g., "Day 1", "Day 8", "Day 15").

How can I make this happen in Highcharts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter), for example:

```js
//set global chart options
$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
    },

    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'FIXME',
        style: {
          color: '#4bb2c5',
        },
      },
      min: 0,
      maxPadding: 0,
    }, ],

    legend: {
      labelFormat: '<span style="font-size: xx-small;">{name}</span>',
    },

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.point.name) + "<br>Cases: " + this.point.y;
      }
    },
  });

  drawGraphMultipleCurves();
});

var plotMultipleCurves = null;

function drawGraphMultipleCurves() {
  //no need to redraw if we've already drawn the graph
  if (plotMultipleCurves != null)
    return;

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves549 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 9, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 8, 0),
      y: 2,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 15, 0),
      y: 7,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 22, 0),
      y: 14,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 17, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 29, 0),
      y: 33,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 10, 24, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 6, 0),
      y: 50,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 13, 0),
      y: 65,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 20, 0),
      y: 97,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 15, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 27, 0),
      y: 128,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 22, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 3, 0),
      y: 192,
      name: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 10, 0),
      y: 239,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 17, 0),
      y: 298,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 12, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 24, 0),
      y: 366,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 19, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
      y: 439,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 8, 0),
      y: 543,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 15, 0),
      y: 623,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 22, 0),
      y: 692,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 29, 0),
      y: 738,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 1, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 5, 0),
      y: 783,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 12, 0),
      y: 819,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 19, 0),
      y: 836,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 26, 0),
      y: 850,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 2, 0),
      y: 864,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 2, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 9, 0),
      y: 875,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 16, 0),
      y: 881,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 13, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 23, 0),
      y: 884,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 20, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 2, 0),
      y: 885,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 9, 0),
      y: 888,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 16, 0),
      y: 890,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 11, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 23, 0),
      y: 892,
      name: Date.UTC(2009, 4, 18, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves805 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 2,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 2, 0),
      y: 4,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 3, 0),
      y: 5,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 28, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 4, 0),
      y: 7,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 5, 0),
      y: 9,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 8, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 6, 0),
      y: 19,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 7, 0),
      y: 34,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 8, 0),
      y: 53,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 9, 0),
      y: 88,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 10, 0),
      y: 114,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 11, 0),
      y: 129,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 12, 0),
      y: 154,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 7, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 13, 0),
      y: 186,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 14, 0),
      y: 212,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 15, 0),
      y: 231,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 16, 0),
      y: 269,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 11, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 17, 0),
      y: 300,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 12, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 18, 0),
      y: 317,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 13, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 19, 0),
      y: 327,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 14, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 20, 0),
      y: 352,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 15, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 21, 0),
      y: 381,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 16, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 22, 0),
      y: 412,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 17, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 23, 0),
      y: 441,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 18, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 24, 0),
      y: 489,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 19, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 25, 0),
      y: 507,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 20, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 26, 0),
      y: 546,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 21, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 27, 0),
      y: 605,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 22, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 28, 0),
      y: 656,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 23, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 29, 0),
      y: 701,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 24, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 30, 0),
      y: 762,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 25, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
      y: 832,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 26, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 894,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 27, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 3, 0),
      y: 941,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 28, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 4, 0),
      y: 959,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 5, 0),
      y: 980,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 30, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 6, 0),
      y: 1005,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 31, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 7, 0),
      y: 1036,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 8, 0),
      y: 1062,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 2, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 9, 0),
      y: 1074,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 3, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 10, 0),
      y: 1105,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 4, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 11, 0),
      y: 1154,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 12, 0),
      y: 1192,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 6, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 13, 0),
      y: 1218,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 7, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 14, 0),
      y: 1268,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 8, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 15, 0),
      y: 1302,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 9, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 16, 0),
      y: 1332,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 10, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 17, 0),
      y: 1357,
      name: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 11, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves534 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 0,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 30, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 30, 0),
      y: 1,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 30, 0),
      y: 5,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 30, 0),
      y: 9,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
      y: 21,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 301,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 2, 0),
      y: 735,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
      y: 964,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 2, 0),
      y: 1041,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
      y: 1044,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 1044,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves550 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 222,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
      y: 546,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 1, 0),
      y: 920,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
      y: 2247,
      name: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 1, 0),
      y: 70613,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 1, 0),
      y: 108834,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
      y: 161916,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 168862,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 1, 0),
      y: 170018,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
      y: 170170,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 1, 0),
      y: 170252,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
      y: 170324,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 170379,
      name: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //shifted cumulative time series
  var cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves537 = [

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 202,
      name: Date.UTC(2006, 11, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 9, 2, 0),
      y: 453,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 2, 0),
      y: 640,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 1, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 10, 30, 0),
      y: 931,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 2, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2001, 11, 31, 0),
      y: 1387,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 3, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 0, 30, 0),
      y: 2256,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 4, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 2, 2, 0),
      y: 3701,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 5, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 3, 1, 0),
      y: 5302,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 6, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 4, 2, 0),
      y: 6353,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 7, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 5, 2, 0),
      y: 7156,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 8, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 6, 2, 0),
      y: 7804,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 9, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 7, 2, 0),
      y: 8351,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 10, 1, 0),
    },

    {
      x: Date.UTC(2002, 8, 1, 0),
      y: 8839,
      name: Date.UTC(2007, 11, 1, 0),
    },

  ];

  //plot the graph
  plotMultipleCurves = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'multipleCurves',
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Outbreak comparison',
    },

    series: [

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves549,
        name: '64% | Australia (2008)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 5,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#800026',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves805,
        name: '52% | Portugal (2012)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 4,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#fd9841',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves534,
        name: '46% | China (2006)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 3,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#fee288',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves550,
        name: '46% | Brazil (2001)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#ffe691',
      },

      {
        data: cumulativeTimeSeriesMultipleCurves537,
        name: '45% | Singapore (2006)',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        color: '#ffeda0',
      },
    ],

    xAxis: [{
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          var relative = this.value - this.axis.dataMin,
              relativeDate = new Date(relative);
          return "Month " + (12 * (relativeDate.getFullYear() - 1970) + relativeDate.getMonth() + 1);
        }
      },
      tickLength: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Time',
      },
    }],

    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Cumulative cases',
      },
      min: 0,
      maxPadding: 0,
    }],

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="multipleCurves"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think `xAxis.labels.formatter` can accomplish this on its own. In your snippet, absolute labels are still being displayed. I need *relative* labels being displayed.

Comment: I think it can. I am not sure if I am not missing anything, but (updated) solution above should resolve your issue. Of course I added only logic for month. Use `this.axis.min` and `this.axis.max` to determine the format (month, day, hours etc.).

Comment: Cool! I think this will indeed work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Highcharts prefers dates in milliseconds, the javascript internal representation, so whenever you use dates on an axis give them in milliseconds. This is the quickest and easiest way to work with dates in Highcharts, as it can usually pretty quickly find the best way to label axes. To convert a date to milliseconds you can use something like:

```
var myDate = +new Date("some date")
```

Once you have the dates in that format, if Highcharts doesn't give you exactly what you want, use the chart options like min, max, dateFormat etc.

Comment: But *how*? I don't see a way to use min/max/dateFormat to specify relative dates.

Comment: Try the 'linkedTo' option..but the main point is, whatever you want to do with dates, do it in millisecond format.